# How do i integrate my application with KIE Workbench?

Tags: jbpm

I am currently trying to integrate JBPM7 into my application. This application used to run with JBPM4.3 and the plan is to upgrade to 7 which adopt BPMN2.0 standards. JBPM has come a long way since version 4 and i like the idea of using the KIE workbench to manage and test the process definitions. This is how i am thinking of using Workbench and appreciate if anyone can share if it is feasible or not.

1. Use of KIE workbench as the main repository to manage my JBPM assets. I do see that KIE workbench has a set of very comprehensive functions to do it. KIE workbench will be deployed on a standalone WildFly10 application server.
2. My JBPM7-based application will be deployed on a different WildFly10 application server. It has a function to connect to the KIE workbench, select a project from the repository, "compile and deploy" a to the application.
3. Once the process definition is deployed to the application, my application should be able to start a process and execute.

I think my first question is whether the above use case is feasible or not. If it is feasible, how can i connect to the KIE workbench to start a process within my application?

Answer (score 0):

Once you deploy to kie-server. You can interact your system with kie-server with REST-API

The documentation of your deployed documentation can be viewed via (generally)

```
{localhost:{port}/kie-server/docs
```

From my point of view, there is nothing wrong with your use-case. This is what I did with mine. 
1. Modelling with KIE-WB
2. Deploy to KIE-server and create a container
3. Start executing processes via REST to KIE-server.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will explore on the rest API that you have mentioned. Do you mind sharing some of your implementations such as unit test cases?